# Should I add a buffer after a Kafka source in Akka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, buffer, akka-stream

According to [this blog post](https://blog.colinbreck.com/maximizing-throughput-for-akka-streams/):

> If the source of the stream polls an external entity for new messages and the downstream processing is non-uniform, inserting a buffer can be crucial to realizing good throughput. For example, a large buffer inserted after the Kafka Consumer from the Reactive Streams Kafka library can improve performance by an order of magnitude in some situations. Otherwise, the source may not poll Kafka fast enough to keep the downstream saturated with work, with the source oscillating between backpressuring and polling Kafka.

The documentation for the [alpakka kafka connnector](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html) doesn't mention that, so I was wondering if it makes sense to use a buffer in this case. Also does the same thing apply to Kafka sinks (should I add a buffer before)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...I was wondering if it makes sense to use a buffer in this case

Consider the following segment from the blog post you quoted:

> ...the downstream processing is non-uniform....

One of the points of that section of the post is to illustrate the similar effects that a user-defined buffer and an asynchronous boundary can have on a stream. The default behavior, in which there are no buffers or asynchronous boundaries, is to enable [operator fusion](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html?language=scala#operator-fusion), which runs a stream in a single actor. This essentially means that for every Kafka message that is consumed, the message must go through the entire pipeline of the stream, from source to sink, before the next message goes through the pipeline. In other words, a message `m2` will not go through the pipeline until the preceding message `m1` is finished processing.

If the processing that occurs downstream from a Kafka connector source is "non-uniform" (i.e, it can take varying amounts of time: sometimes the processing happens quickly, sometimes it takes a while), then introducing a buffer or an asynchronous boundary could improve the overall throughput. This is because a buffer or asynchronous boundary can allow the source to continue consuming Kafka messages even if the downstream processing happens to take a long time. That is, if `m1` takes a long time to process, the source could consume messages `m2`, `m3`, etc. (until the buffer is full), without waiting for `m1` to finish. As Colin Breck states in his post:

> The buffer improves performance by decoupling stages, allowing the upstream or downstream to continue to process elements, on average, even if one of them is busy processing a relatively expensive workload.

This potential performance boost doesn't apply for all situations. Again quoting Breck:

> Similar to the `async` method discussed in the previous section, it should be noted that inserting buffers indiscriminately will not improve performance and simply consume additional resources. If adjacent workloads are relatively uniform, the addition of a buffer will not change the performance, as the overall performance of the stream will simply be dominated by the slowest processing stage.

One obvious way to determine whether using a buffer (i.e., `.buffer`) makes sense in your case is to try it. You might also try adding an asynchronous boundary (i.e., `.async`) instead. Compare the following three approaches--(1) the default fused behavior without buffering, (2) `.buffer`, and (3) `.async`--and see which one results in the best performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's still not clear to me if it makes sense to use a buffer without using aync, especially when you say 'every Kafka message that is consumed, the message must go through the entire pipeline of the stream, from source to sink'. Would the buffer change anything?

Comment: After spending a lot of time testing different configurations, I figured out I need to add a buffer to both kafka sink and source. I don't need to add async boundary, the sink is actually async for the most part. Also I've increase the producer parallelism, which helped (see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html#settings)